# code makes two primary keys?

Tags: sql

I saw this on the postgresql [create table page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html):

```
CREATE TABLE films (
    code        char(5),
    title       varchar(40),
    did         integer,
    date_prod   date,
    kind        varchar(10),
    len         interval hour to minute,
    CONSTRAINT code_title PRIMARY KEY(code,title)
);
```

I get constraints like `CHECK (price > 0)` but I don't know what this means where primary key is passed code and title like parameters.

Is this setting both to the primary key?

Is it possible to have two primary keys?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not two primary keys, it a single, *composite* primary key.

It means that the primary key is made up of the two columns `code` and `title` (hence the `code_title` constraint name).

So, while you can have rows with duplicate codes and duplicate titles, no two rows can have the same `code/title` combination:

```
code  title
----  -----
0000  aaaaa    Okay.
0000  bbbbb    Okay.
1111  bbbbb    Okay.
0000  aaaaa    ** No! Conflicts with first row. **
```

Comment: so this just throws an error if a product has the same code and title?

Answer (score 0):

As paxdiablo said what you have is a composite key.

```
+-------+
|A B C D|
+-------+
|1 2 2 3|
+-------+
|2 3 2 4|
+-------+
|3 2 2 3|
+-------+
|4 4 3 2|
+-------+
```

-A could be a primary key here as it has no duplicate rows

```
+-------+
|A B C D|
+-------+
|1 2 3 2|
+-------+
|1 3 2 3|
+-------+
|2 2 3 2|
+-------+
|1 1 3 3|
+-------+
```

-A could not be a primary key here as it has duplicate rows
-A,B could be a composite key, combined they have no duplicate rows (12, 13, 22, 11)

Further, no it is not possible to have more than one primary key. After your primary key you can have unique keys which would prevent that column from having a duplicates, but the primary key is automatically set as an index.